# How to check for '\n' character using getline() for c-strings

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to increment the variable int lines everytime getline encounters a '\n' character in an input file.  However, my variable isn't being incremented after a new line and I'm assuming maybe I'm not checking the buffer correctly that I'm loading the characters of the line into. Here is my code with much of it simplified:

```
int lines = 0;
while(input.getline(buffer, 100))
{

if(buffer[0] == '\n')
   lines++;
}
```

File format(I want it to increment once it encounters the '\n' between the two lines of data):

```
20012 CSCI 109 04 90 1 25

-- ID days_constraint start_contraint
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Since `getline`, by definition, gets lines, why do you think you need to check anything? If `getline` succeeded, it got a line.

Comment: if getline return successfully then a new line has been read, you just need to increase the counter

Comment: I think you need to clarify that by "returned successfully" you mean that the `failbit` isn't set—right?

Comment: @David - using `std::istream::getline`, it doesn't actually get a line if the line exceeded the buffer size. OP may want to know whether the person entered 100 or fewer characters and pressed Enter , or whether there was more input on the same line that we haven't read yet.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It's hard to know because the question doesn't say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(buffer[0] == '\n')
```

That will only work if the newline is the first character in the line, i.e. if it's a blank line. So you're only counting blank lines. It should have been:

```
if(buffer[strlen(buffer)] == '\n')
```

But as @DavidSchwartz points out, you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you used `std::basic_istream::getline`, you don't need the check whether '\n' in your buffer, because '\n' was used as the delimiter. So just increment every successful `getline` is OK.

```
int lines = 0;
while(input.getline(buffer, 100))
{
   lines++;
}
//other handle exception logic
if (input.fail()
{
// lines number is not valid
}
if (input.bad())
{
//......
}
```

Assume file is valid and lines less than 100, or you should add exception handle logic.

Comment: This won't work if you have lines longer than 100 characters. I think you also need to check the `failbit`.

Comment: @DaoWen, thanks your comments, yes, if lines longer than 100, failbit should be check. So as other exceptions.